# How can I customize the tooltips / hover for VS Code Explorer items?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Would it be possible to have a customizable popup when hovering over a file in the explorer?

Currently it just shows the filename and git status on hover.

I'm thinking like a description that could be added to a comment at the top of the file.

[image: VS Code File Hover]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to *add* things using [the `FileDecoration` API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileDecoration) (see the `tooltip` property). You'd need to implement [`FileDecorationProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileDecorationProvider) and pass it to a call to `registerFileDecorationProvider`.